# Error: Could not load the "cm_photo_library_white" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier ""

Tags: cosmicmind

I started getting this error recently, possibly after the recent update?

To test I created a new project, added to the storyboard a Tab Bar Controller with its 2 VCs. I set one of the pages tab bar items to any of the added icons from Material. Build/Run the app, when the tabbarcont tries to load I get the error:

Error: Could not load the "cm_photo_library_white" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier...

Any Suggestions, others seeing this?

Just got into iOS development, and found Material. Plan to use it and Firebase on an app! Love what you've done with Material. Expect kickbacks once my app starts out int he wild :)

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods to load Material? If so, what version of CocoaPods?

Comment: @CosmicMind Using CocoaPods 1.0.0 - just updated material this AM to 1.4.6. still getting the same error.

Comment: @CosmicMind, I found that If I remove the existing Assets.xcassets, and copy/paste the Assets file from the Material resources folder into my apps folder groups it works.

Comment: Its unfortunate you need to do that. There seems to be a very small number of people facing icon issues with CocoaPods. We are not able to replicate the issue, so it is challenging to solve. What we have figured though, is that CocoaPods doesn't seem to clear the cache of the old build. So cleaning the build folders, and deleting User Derived data has been very helpful.

Comment: @CosmicMind Thats for the response anyways! I have another version of the app where I am attempting to write it all via code, sans the storyboard. I must admit I find it more difficult as I am new to xcode/swift/ios dev. But that seems to be the way you suggest going?

Any resources you can point me to that help with understanding controllers setup via code?

Comment: To learn how to setup controllers and such with iOS, I would start with understanding the MVC paradigm that iOS so heavily relies on (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html), once you have an understanding of that, you can move to data-driven architectures. You are welcome to bring your questions here https://gitter.im/CosmicMind/Material :)

Answer (score 0):

I have some error.
I select icon in StoryBoard with Xcode autocomplete.
[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoW8s.png)
It can't work.

But `button.setImage(Icon.cm.arrowBack, for: .normal)` work :)